# Put language name in latex listing

Tags: latex, lstlisting

I would like to put the name of the language of a listing on the listing. The linked image illustrates this: In the upper right corener its said that this listing shows a java program.
[Language of the listing is denoted at the upper right corner](http://pl.vc/3t2a4)

Comment: Hi! Can you restore the image? To not leave this unanswered :)